# TypeScript syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: vim, typescript, vim-syntax-highlighting

I installed the [typescript plugin](https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim) via

```
git clone https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/typescript-vim
```

and inserted

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ts   setfiletype typescript
```

into by `~/.vim.rc`. Linting via [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt) and tsc/tslint works well, and

```
:set syntax
```

shows `syntax=typescript`. However,

```
:syntax
```

shows `No Syntax items defined for this buffer` and highlighting doesn't work.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: I installed [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) and the `au ...` instruction in the `~/.vimrc` is all I need.

Comment: I think over time this has changed a bit. I went to this plugin's github and now it only requires this `git clone https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim.git ~/.vim/pack/typescript/start/typescript-vim` to actually work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What was missing from `~/.vimrc` is a specification of where to find the plugin, i.e.,

```
Plugin 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
```

Highlighting works now.

Comment: I have installed Vundel first, and Plugin 'same as above'. Still not work. After I manually  copy the files to /usr/share/vim/vim74, it worked. I will list the details below.

Comment: Where do you type this?!

Answer (score 28):

Vim 8 has native package loading. Leave `.vimrc` alone and just do this:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/typescript/start
$ cd ~/.vim/pack/typescript/start
$ git clone https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim.git
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when you move to a new machine and need this set up again, you have nothing in .vimrc that helps you install the plugins you've been using.

Comment: I have .vim as a git repo, and install plugins with `git submodule add` instead of `git clone`, so it's all tracked

Answer (score 3):

There are not so many postings when I searched on line for solving this problem. I installed Vundel, according to the instruction, and add the Plugin line to my ~/.vimrc file.  Also added one line

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ts setlocal filetype=typescript
```

to vimrc. Still not working.  Then I manually copied the typescript.vim file in each of the directories cloned from git: git@github.com:leafgarland/typescript-vim.git

```
compiler ftdetect ftplugin indent syntax
```

to their corresponding directories, respectively, to the /usr/share/vim/vim74/. If you use vim8.0 the directory basename will be vim80.

It started to work. This may not be a good solution, but at least it get me started.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. In the ftdetect/typescript.vim file the following options are set: 

`" use set filetype to override default filetype=xml for *.ts files`

`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ts  set filetype=typescript`

`" use setfiletype to not override any other plugins like ianks/vim-tsx`

`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tsx setfiletype typescript`

it would probably be safest just to copy that into .vimrc

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers still work, vim now has TypeScript syntax highlighting built in.

So you can also just **upgrade to Vim 8.2** (actually, I think v8.1.1486 is sufficient).